# What is the formal definition of an "information source"?

Tags: random-variables, information-theory

My (naive) intuition of an information source is that it's just a "black box" that emits symbols ranging over a finite alphabet. What's missing from this definition?

On the wikipedia page for an [information source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_source_(mathematics)), it says:

> In mathematics, an information source is a sequence of **random variables** ranging over a finite alphabet Γ, having a **stationary distribution**.

I have bolded the two parts that I'm confused about.

First, the wikipedia page for [stationary distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_distribution) isn't very helpful since it's a disambiguation page and I'm not sure which link is relevant to the formal definition of an information source.

And second, my conception of a "random variable" was that it maps events (of a probability space) to symbols. Is the term "random variables" appropriate here? Wouldn't it make more sense to say "an information source is a sequence of **symbols** ranging over a finite alphabet"? By using the term "random variables" the Wikipedia definition implies that an information source is a sequence of *functions*.

If someone could correct my understanding here that'd be great!

Comment: wiki doesnt say something wrong about the definition of an information source. your own definition is also not wrong but probably incomplete.

Comment: My problem is I don't understand the use of "random variable" and "stationary distribution" in this context.

Comment: random variable is a function defined from the sample space to another measurable space. If you have a collection of random variables, they do create random samples, i.e. a random vector as in your definition. whenever you want to obtain another vector you can get it from the collection of random variables you have. Stationary means that the distributions of the random variables are **fixed** and do not change in time. make sense?

Comment: Hmm... I still don't understand how an information source emits a sequence of *functions* rather than a sequence of symbols. The probability distribution of the different symbols is fixed? I think that makes sense if they're including the conditional probability distribution too. Because obviously the instantaneous probability distribution could change (i.e. is *not* fixed) depending on the symbols that were most recently emitted (as, I believe is the case with the simple [markov information source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_information_source))

Comment: it actually does not emit a sequence of functions, as I told you before it emits only sequence of symbols. The source has the capability of outputing any kind of sequence which can infact be possible. For this one needs a set of random variables.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I see my mistake now. The wiki definition reads "an information source **is a** sequence of random variables" but I read it as "an information source **emits a** sequence of random variables". Now that you've helped me notice that error it makes much more sense. So an information source can "emit" a *vector* of symbols generated by a *vector* of random variables. Thanks for your help! Feel free to put your comments into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: exactly. okay thanks.

Comment: Notice that the restriction to "finite alphabets" is not necessary. The symbols can even be real numbers. And also the "time" can be continuous. This, in general, amounts to a "stochastic process".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki doesn't say something wrong about the definition of an information source. Your own definition is also not wrong but probably incomplete.

Random variable is a function defined from a sample space to a measurable space. If you have a collection of random variables, they do create random samples, i.e. a random vector as in your definition. whenever you want to obtain another vector you can get it from the collection of random variables you have. Stationary means that the distributions of the random variables are fixed and do not change in time.

A set of random variables actually does not emit a sequence of functions, it emits only sequence of symbols. The source has the capability of outputing any kind of sequence which can in fact be possible. For this, one needs a set of random variables.

Comment: (Note to future visitors to this page: see comments on my original post for more context to Seyhmus's answer)